# Tools for language manipulation

Tags: java, python, .net, pdf

I have a problem that I'd like to resolve and would like to know about tools and approaches. The task is not easy but I need to clean up pdf ebooks and get them ready for text to speech so I can make mp3s of them. It's a loaded question but I'd like to start somewhere. The main problem right now is how to remove book references from this ebook. Of course strategies will vary depending on format but on this particular ebook the references might look something like this:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."(5)

and a reference at bottom of the same page:

> (5) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

The reference at the bottom seem to be smaller font size from the rest of the text. Perhaps I can use that to my advantage. I have used regular expressions but on most occassions it don't quite cut the mustard for the whole job. I need several tools for this and I know about iText, pdfminer, but I have not quite learned those yet. I'm not quite looking for a text extractor, I can already do that. I'm looking for something more sophisticated, perhaps even language processing, who knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to start with NLTK, it's a Stanford library for natural language tasks. I found this basic tutorial for Named Entity Extraction, which it sounds like you're trying to do.

http://www.nltk.org/

http://www.nltk.org/howto/relextract.html

There's several other apis that handle Entity Extraction, here's a list from a Quora question:
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-entity-extraction-API-+-service